# Angular-Cli camelCase name

Tags: angular, angular-cli, naming-conventions

It seems that when I used angular cli to generate components,services etc.by this command and name of component

```
ng g component myApp
```

It generate component folder and other files such as

> my-app.component.ts

instead myapp.component.ts

My question is,Is there any command to generate components,services etc. with  camelCase name.

I research for it,but nothing works.

Comment: As of this writing, this feature is not available, but an issue has been opened on the angular-cli GitHub repo and it should be implemented soon.
See this link for more info: [angular-cli camelCase naming convention](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6705)

Comment: Please note that the CLI follows the Angular Style Guide: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide.

Answer (score 9):

Angular Style Guide explicitly says to use `my-app.component.ts` for file names.

- dash-case (or "kebab-case"): descriptive part of file names, component selectors

Reference: https://angular.io/guide/glossary