# Ng cli how generate component with desired name

Tags: angular

Is there any way to use ng to generate a component with the desired name.

If I run 'ng g c gridTest1' it instead generates a component in files grid-test1 so I have to rename all the files to gridTest1.component which is what I asked for in the first place.

Comment: Please add what is your expectation with the command to make your problem more clear.

Comment: `ng g component --help` is all you need

Answer (score 2):

i tried to do that and also i couldn't,

finally i found there is an issue opened on the angular-cli GitHubrepo,https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6705

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, you would prefer to use camelCase in your coding style. 
[Angular-Cli camelCase name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44172438/angular-cli-camelcase-name)

Apparently, the official angular style guide does not support that